# GCP Uptime Metric is giving unreliable alerts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, monitoring, stackdriver

Trying to get an alert when the GCE VM is in down state by creating Alerting Policy.

Metric: `compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime`

Resource : VM instance

And made the configuration that in order to trigger an alert when this condition is absent for 3 minutes.

To simulate this above behavior , I have stopped the VM but it is not triggering an alert , meanwhile data is not visible in graph of the alerting policy

Have attached trigger configuration

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with the alerting policy details ?

Comment: Alerting Policy Details : I'm leaving Filter & Group fields empty and Aggregator & Period kepping it as default values i.e., (None & 5 minutes) , And this condition triggers if "Any time series violates" when the condition "is absent" for "3 minutes".

Comment: What is your goal here ? To just get alerts when the VM is non-responsive / off ? Maybe you just want a simple [uptime check](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the metrics are giving reliable alerts when the VM is in stopped state,which are compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime or uptime of the monitoring agent or cpu utilization metrics until you create alerting poilicy with MQL - Monitoring Query language.

"metrics associated with TERMINATED or DELETED Google Cloud resources are not considered for metric-absence policies. This means you can't use metric-absence policies to test for TERMINATED or DELETED Google Cloud VMs."
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/types-of-conditions#metric-absence

So as per the above statement we cannot use metic absence policy for stopped vm - As It goes to terminated state after it stopped for sometime.The reason is , it calculates the instance stop time only when it becomes running state again.

But when you configure the same condition with MQL with the same set of metrics , Metric-absence policies works without any issues.

Sample:

Instead of configuring the condition by selecting resource & metric , go to Query Editor and type the below query for getting the alert when the Development environment VM is not in running state for 3 minutes.

```
fetch gce_instance
| metric 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime'
| filter (metadata.user_labels.env == 'dev')
| group_by 1m, [value_uptime_aggregate: aggregate(value.uptime)]
| every 1m
| absent_for 180s
```

Not sure this is the bug or not , but this is limitation when we configure the alerting condition in a traditional way and we can resolve this by leveraging MQL.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior you're describing is unusual.

I reproduced your case and created the exact alerting policy using the same metric `compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime` with the same settings. I forwarded all alerts to my e-mail.

Unfortunatelly I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior. After playing with various settings (agregation, absence time) and I was getting alerting emails.

Try maybe setting the alerting policy again. If your goal is just to monitor the state of the VM (responding or no) then you can use any other metrics such as `cpu usage` which will be absent when the VM is off (or unresponsive).

Finally you can try [installing monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/installation#gce-ui-install) on your VM which will give you more metrics available thus more information on the machine.

Have a look at [how to manage alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui) documentation which may be usefull to you. Additionally this documentation describes [alerting policies types](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/types-of-conditions) and how to choose apropriate one for you use case.

Ultimately try creating another VM and set up alerting policy for it. If that doesn't work your best shot is to go to [Google IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and file a new bug report and it will be handled by the product team - however this may take some (or a lot) of time depending on the issue.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor yes but still it is not giving reliable alerts when the condition is absent.@Wojtek_B I'm wondering whether stopping the VM simulates this behavior of metric data absent.

Comment: As described in my answer - I did reproduce your issue; while the VM was stopped the metric was absent.